# Signal Handler for Flask application with Gunicorn + Eventlet

Tags: python, gunicorn, eventlet, signal-handling

Currently, I am trying to add a signal handler that correctly updates the database state whenever our server is re-started/updated by listening for SIGTERM interrupts. Our Flask app is on a Gunicorn server monkey-patched with eventlet.

However, whenever the restart happens, we get the error from eventlet 'do not call blocking functions from the mainloop'. How do we get around this issue?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm having a similar issue did you manged to resolve it?